Distribution of Uniform Order Statistics' Sum
$Y_1,\cdots,Y_n\overset{i.i.d}{\sim} U(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ , calculate $Y_{(1)}+Y_{(n)}$ 's distribution
Here my approach:
$$\begin{aligned}
f_{Y_{(1)}+Y_{(n)}}(y)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)}}(x,y-x)I(-1/2 \leq x\leq 1/2,x\leq y-x)dx\\
&=\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{y}{2}}n(n-1)(F(y-x)-F(x))^{n-2}f(y-x)f(x)dx\\
&=\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{y}{2}}n(n-1)(y-2x)^{n-2}dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}n(y-2x)^{n-1}\bigg|_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{y}{2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}n(y+1)^{n-1},y\in[-1,1]
\end{aligned}$$
However when I try to varify my answer, I get:
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{2}n(y+1)^{n-1}dy=\frac{1}{2}(y+1)^{n}\bigg|_{-1}^{1}=2^{n-1}\neq 1,n\geq 2$$
Where did I go wrong?

As framago pointed out, I overlooked $I(y - x < \frac{1}{2})$.

The joint pdf is $$f_{Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)}}(m,M)=n(n-1)(M-m)^{n-2}\,\mathcal I\Bigl\{-\frac12\le m \le M\le\frac12\Bigr\}.$$
Fix $y\in[-1,1]$. We have
\begin{aligned}
f_{Y_{(1)}+Y_{(n)}}(y)&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_{Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)}}(x,y-x)\,dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}n(n-1)(y-2x)^{n-2}\,\mathcal I\Bigl\{-\frac12\le x \le y-x\le\frac12\Bigr\}\,dx.\end{aligned}
Factorizing the indicator function we get the integration bounds
\begin{aligned}
&\mathcal I\Bigl\{-\frac12\le x \le y-x\le\frac12\Bigr\}\\{}={}&\mathcal I\Bigl\{-\frac12\le x\Bigr\} \,\mathcal I\Bigl\{x\le y-x\Bigr\}\,\mathcal I\Bigl\{y-x\le\frac12\Bigr\}\\{}={}&\mathcal I\Bigl\{x\ge-\frac12\Bigr\} \,\mathcal I\Bigl\{x\le \frac{y}{2}\Bigr\}\,\mathcal I\Bigl\{x\ge y-\frac12\Bigr\}\\{}={}&\mathcal I\Bigl\{x\ge\max\Bigl(-\frac12,y-\frac12\Bigr)\Bigr\} \,\mathcal I\Bigl\{x\le \frac{y}{2}\Bigr\}\\{}={}&\mathcal I\Bigl\{x\ge-\frac12+y\,\mathcal I\{y>0\}\Bigr\} \,\mathcal I\Bigl\{x\le \frac{y}{2}\Bigr\}.
\end{aligned}
Hence the integral becomes
\begin{aligned}
f_{Y_{(1)}+Y_{(n)}}(y)&=\int_{-\frac12+y\,\mathcal I\{y>0\}}^{\frac{y}{2}}n(n-1)(y-2x)^{n-2}\,dx\\
&=\frac12n\Bigl(y+1-2y\,\mathcal I\{y>0\}\Bigr)^{n-1}\\
&=\frac12n\Bigl(1-\lvert y\rvert\Bigr)^{n-1}.
\end{aligned}

+1.  Perhaps more commonly seen is $X_i \overset{i.i.d}{\sim} U[0,1]$ and $\frac1{2}(X_{(1)}+X_{(n)})$ having density $n(1-|2x-1|)^{n-1}$ on $[0,1]$
